# Serialize java.time.Duration to json as milliseconds only, using Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, java-time, jackson2

I am trying to find a way to configure the object serialization process (using Jackson) to serialize a Duration field as milliseconds (not seconds+milliseconds, which seems to be the default).

I have a class that represents some event for example:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeEvent {

  private Duration durationOfEvent;
}
```

If I run the following code, which creates an instance and obtains a json representation then I get the output shown below

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis(500);
SomeEvent someEvent = SomeEvent.builder().durationOfEvent(duration).build();

ObjectMapper objectMapper = enhancedObjectMapper();

String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(someEvent);
System.out.println(json);
```

Output:

```
{"durationOfEvent":0.500000000}
```

What I would like to obtain is:

```
{"durationOfEvent":500}
```

The reason I would like it as milliseconds is that the process that consumes the json can handle milliseconds easier than a decimal number.

I would prefer to add some annotation or custom serialization for this specific field in this class, and not for all instances of java.time.Duration, as there are other classes in the application that also use Duration, and I don't want to affect them. I previously tried a custom serializer that handled all Durations, but that approach broke tests related to other classes which use Duration.

The version of the Jackson library I have is: 2.12.4

Comment: I don't think you should have a `Duration` object in your `SomeEvent` class. Use instead a `number type` and then populate it with the `Duration.ofMillis()`.  Tested your code and I got this : `{"durationOfEvent":{"seconds":0,"units":["SECONDS","NANOS"],"zero":false,"negative":false,"nano":500000000}}`

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by telling Jackson
that you want the `Duration durationOfEvent` property
to be serialized by your own serializer.
You do this by adding a [`@JsonSerialize` annotation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) to
the property in your class `SomeEvent`.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MyDurationSerializer.class)
private Duration durationOfEvent;
```

You can implement your serializer as a very simple
subclass of [`JsonSerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html) which just gets
the milliseconds and writes it as a JSON number.

```
public class MyDurationSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Duration> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Duration value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        long milliseconds = value.toMillis();
        gen.writeNumber(milliseconds);
    }
}
```

---

Another simpler way is to use Jackson's `DurationSerializer` and
configure it with `@JsonFormat` to your desired output format.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = DurationSerializer.class)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER_INT,
            without = JsonFormat.Feature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS)
private Duration durationOfEvent;
```

---

For both ways described above the JSON output will look like this:

```
{"durationOfEvent":500}
```